# Exception handling using enterprise library

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library

We are using Enterprise Library to connect to data base (SQLServer 2008)

Below is my code in repository to handle exceptions, related to our database:

```
try{
   ----;
   -----;       
}

catch(system.data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{

}
```

Is there any "Enterprise library" exception class to catch the raise exceptions?

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: http://enggtech.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/the-exception-handling-application-block-microsoft-enterprise-library-5-0/

Comment: do accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

you want this : [Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649552.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these learning resources for the Exception Handling Application Block (EHAB):

- start with reading [Chapter 3 - Error Management Made Exceptionally Easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953192%28PandP.50%29.aspx) from the Developer's Guide
- corresponding code samples can be found [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/releases/view/46741#DownloadId=140302)
- do the [hands-on lab](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6932) on EHAB
- if needed consult with the [reference documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664698%28PandP.50%29.aspx) and the [class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.exceptionhandling%28PandP.50%29.aspx)
- for questions and support, use the EntLib [forum](http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions) - there's a dedicated team answering those questions.